# Blender API: Selecting Camera by ID

Tags: blender

I get the name of the camera selected from the user via a camera picker.

I get the selected camera.name with

```
camera_object = bpy.data.objects.get(obj.camera.name)
```

I want to set the choosen camera as active

```
bpy.context.scene.camera =  camera_object
```

It is working but when the name of the camera is not same that the ID then it is not working.
See the difference in the outliner where I have a problem:

[image]

How could I solve this?
Thanks in advance,